# CodeIgniter 404 on method

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm having a little problem

This is my controller CapturistaCtrl.php:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class CapturistaCtrl extends CI_Controller {

    public function index(){
        echo "index";
    }

    public function alta(){
        echo "alta";
    }
}
```

this is my routes.php

```
 <?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['default_controller'] = 'Welcome';
$route['capturista'] = 'CapturistaCtrl';
```

on config.php:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/captura';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

and .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /captura/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

If I put this URL: http://localhost/captura/capturista I get the text "index" displayed, it means the index() method on my controller works, but if I put http://localhost/captura/capturista/alta I'm getting a 404 page.

Comment: Just read the CodeIgniter documentation and follow its tutorial lesson.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using regex capturing group `(...)`.

**Try:**

```
$route['capturista(.*)'] = 'CapturistaCtrl$1';
```

**Alternative**, using :any wildcard.

```
$route['capturista/(:any)'] = 'CapturistaCtrl/$1';
$route['capturista'] = 'CapturistaCtrl/index';
```

Comment: http://localhost/captura/capturista/alta works now but http://localhost/captura/capturista doesn't work anymore

Edit: Using $route['capturista/(:any)'] = 'CapturistaCtrl/$1'; below  $route['capturista'] = 'CapturistaCtrl'; it seems to work, thanks, but is that the best solution? I need the use 2 lines per controller?

Comment: Updated my answer. Using just one line.

Answer (score 0):

```
****controller code****
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * 
 */
class CapturistaCtrl extends CI_controller
{

    public function index(){
        echo "index";
    }

    public function alta(){
        echo "alta";
    }
}

**routes.php**

$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
$route['capturista'] = 'CapturistaCtrl';
$route['capturista/(:any)'] = 'CapturistaCtrl/$1'; 
// (or any one )$route['capturista/alta'] = 'CapturistaCtrl/alta';


**.htaccess**

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>


**config.php**

$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
remove (index.php)
$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'index.php';
remove (index.php)
$config['index_page'] = '';
```